# Timestamped screenshots with selenium IDE

Tags: java, screenshot, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE for simple testcases and some automation. I have not much knowhow on Java or Javascript.

Currently I work on a testcase that captures several screenshots. Therefore I need a unique filename e.g. `myscreenshot_YYYYMMDDHHss.png`.

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please show us exact code you are facing issue with. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Ask specific questions to get satisfactory answers.

Comment: You can start with the `Calendar` or `Timestamp` classes of java to get the time and then do a string concatenation in Java, You should find answers for these subquestions from the official documentation or on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

**Command:**`storeEval`

**Target:** `var d = new Date(); var m = ((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1); m+"-"+d.getDate()+"-"+d.getFullYear()+"_"+d.getHours()+"-"+d.getMinutes();`

**Value:** `date`

*next row..*

**Command:** `captureEntirePageScreenshot`

**Target:** `C:\\SampleDirectory\\${date}.png`

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks, Rodel. This is exactly what I was looking for!